# jquery cycle thru list one at a time when keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input box and below it, a basic list.  When you press arrow-down (or arrow-up) from within the input box, I'd like to highlight/change-background of the first list item (as if it was being selected).

```
<div><input id="frmartist" type="text" value=""/></div>
<ul id="artistlist">
    <li id="artist-1">artist 1</li>
    <li id="artist-2">artist 2</li>
    <li id="artist-3">artist 3</li>
    <li id="artist-4">artist 4</li>
    <li id="artist-5">artist 5</li>
</ul>
```

If you press arrow-down again, the 2nd item would be highlighted.  If you press down again, the 3rd item would be highlighted.

And if you were to press arrow-up, then the 2nd item would be highlighted again.

How can I control this behavior with jquery/javascript?  I'm guessing I should track which item is highlighted, but outside of that, I think I'm clueless.

I'm catching the arrow-up and arrow-down by using e.which === 40 and e.which === 38, but I'm confused as to where to go accessing the first item of the list.

Any tips?

Comment: im working on your solution

Comment: done im posting answer starting point

Comment: @undefined: it's similar to the autocomplete widget of jquery.  but my results are not in json format (and I have no control over it either) so I believe I'm SOL with it.

Comment: i updated it so up arrow works too i hope my solution helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Track the state of the highlighted artist in a variable. Then attach an event to the window which monitors the `keyup` event and looks for 38 or 40. Update the state of the highlighted artist, and then update the view to reflect the change based on the key event.

Like this, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9bFAb/

html:

```
<div><input id="frmartist" type="text" value=""/></div>
<ul id="artistlist">
 <li id="artist-1" class="highlighted">artist 1</li>
 <li id="artist-2">artist 2</li>
 <li id="artist-3">artist 3</li>
 <li id="artist-4">artist 4</li>
 <li id="artist-5">artist 5</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.highlighted{
 background-color:red;
}
```

js:

```
var artistIndex = 1;
function hightlightArtist(index){
 var selector = "#artist-" + index;
 $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
 $(selector).addClass('highlighted');
}
window.onkeyup = function(e){
  var code = e.which;
  if( code == 40 ){
    if( artistIndex < 5 )artistIndex++;
  }//up
  if( code == 38){
    if( artistIndex > 1 ) artistIndex--;
  }//down
  hightlightArtist(artistIndex);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that doesn't use any global JavaScript state. This makes it simpler than solutions that do use such state, as here we inspect the markup to find its current state. This solution is thus more robust in some ways (no data redundancy, cannot have out of sync state).

As you were saying, you must track the currently selected element. But if you do your highlighting using a dedicated CSS class, then the CSS class itself can serve as the marker indicating which element is currently highlighted.

The below functions for moving up and down, respectively, should do the trick. Just call the right one from each keypress handler. The currently highlighted list item is assumed to have CSS class `highlighted`. I used a helper function called `moveBy` to achieve maximum code reuse.

EDITED: rewrote the example using jQuery's `index` to achieve more straightforward support for page up, down, etc.

```
var moveUp = function(list) { moveBy(-1, list); };
var moveDown = function(list) { moveBy(+1, list); };
var pageUp = function(list) { moveBy(-10, list); };
var pageDown = function(list) { moveBy(+10, list); };
var first = function(list) { moveBy(-$(list).children().length, list); };
var last = function(list) { moveBy(+$(list).children().length, list); };


var moveBy = function(delta, list) {
    list = $(list);
    var count = list.children().length;

    var current = list.children('.highlighted');
    if (!current.length) {
        // There are no highlighted items.
        // Highlight the first or the last, depending on whether
        // delta is up (negative), or down (positive).
        list.get(delta > 0 ? 0 : count - 1).addClass('highlighted');
    } else {
        // Find the next element according to delta. Do not wrap around.
        var nextIndex = current.index() + delta;
        nextIndex = Math.max(0, Math.min(count - 1, nextIndex));
        var next = list.get(nextIndex);

        // Switch highlighting.
        current.removeClass('highlighted');
        next.addClass('highlighted');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting point for you. Up and Down arrows both work. If you press key to try to get past the end or past the beginning of the list it will wrap around correctly which you might like too. I hope it helps you.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/YnpW3/2/

CODE:

HTML:

```
<div><input id="frmartist" type="text" value=""/></div>
<ul id="artistlist">
    <li id="artist-1">artist 1</li>
    <li id="artist-2">artist 2</li>
    <li id="artist-3">artist 3</li>
    <li id="artist-4">artist 4</li>
    <li id="artist-5">artist 5</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
    var h = 0;
function lich()
{
  $("li").css({color: "black"});
  $("li").eq(h).css({color: "Red"});
}
lich();
$(window).on("keyup", function(e){
   if(e.keyCode == 40)
   {
       h++;
       if(h > $("li").length - 1)
       {
         h= 0;        
       }
       lich();

   }
  else if(e.keyCode ==38)
  {
       h--;
       if(h < 0)
       {
         h= $("li").length - 1;        
       }
       lich();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### [jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eyimun/2/edit)

this will also loop, and it doesn't care how much artists you have ;)

```
var $artists = $('#artistlist li'),
    nOfArtists = $artists.length,
    curr = 0;


$artists.eq( curr ).addClass('highlight');


$(window).on('keyup', function( e ){
  var key = e.which;

  if(key == 40){
    curr++ ;
    curr = curr % nOfArtists ;
  }else if(key==38){
    curr-- ;
    if(curr === -1){
      curr = nOfArtists-1; 
    }
  }
  $artists.eq(curr).addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
  
});
```